# PHP webservice with insert query

Tags: php, mysql, json, web-services

I am new to coding, I am creating a webservice which will take 3 parameters and submit that into the database and revert with json response something like

```
{"Status":"Success", "Id":"123"}
```

currently i have code for selecting all tuple of a table and resulting in json using array(); but here i want object only (i guess), please help..

attaching code of selecting data from database webservice,

```
$query = "SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE id = ".$user_id;
$result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Error query: '.$query);
$posts = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $posts[] = array('post'=>$post);
    }
}

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts));
```

Please help for creating webservice of insert data query. Thanks.

Comment: What is your current output?

Comment: This is the select query called in the webservice. It results in giving all the data of the table through array().

Comment: I am not clear about you problem but anyway plz check here for json encode http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php , and i think you have done something wrong in while loop, try to use print_r for checking your array then go for json_decode

Comment: how can i pass non array value through json encode.

Comment: You have to check a condition if that matches then Status should be Success and ID can be attached to it and JSON encode this combo..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can understand you have to check something on the server side and on being successful it should return JSON response as

> {"Status":"Success" , "ID": 123}

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE id = ".$user_id;
$result = mysqli_query($query,$link) or die("Error" . mysqli_error());  //Error Printing
$posts = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if(conditions etc...)
    {
        $posts['Status'] = "success";
        $post['ID] = $user_id;
     }
     else {
      blah blah
     }
 }


header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($posts);
```

This will enocde a response having status and ID of the user, same as you wanted

> {"Status":"Success", "Id":"123"}